# Firebase not triggering push notifications in iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, push-notification

I am not able to get the push notifications to trigger in my iOS. It was working earlier and now it no longer is. This is my pod file:

```
    platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

def common_pods

pod 'lottie-ios', '~> 3.1.1'
pod 'jot'
pod 'CrittercismSDK'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'PieCharts'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.8.2'
pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 5.0.0'
pod 'Charts', '~> 3.3.0'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '2.0.6'
pod 'Mixpanel-swift', '~> 2.6.3'
pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 5.0.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 5.0.0'
pod 'Instructions', '~> 1.3.1'
pod 'Highcharts', '~> 6.1.0'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'SideMenu', '~> 5.0.3'
pod 'MZFormSheetPresentationController'
pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView', '~> 4.8.0'
pod 'googleapis', :path => '.'
pod 'JJFloatingActionButton'
pod 'SnapKit', '~> 4.2.0'
```

Xcode 11.5 on macOS 10.15.5, test device is on iOS 13.4.1

I am guessing it has something to do with my pods being out of date, but would also like to know from someone who is familiar with this on what else may cause this to happen. I believe we had recently updated our app's APNs certificates in the firebase console, but the parameters in `GoogleService-Info.plist` did not modify anything

Comment: FirebaseMessaging is on version 4.5.0 and you're still on 2.0.6? I would remove all the version specifications, run `pod update` and add them back only if you need them for a specific reason.

Comment: Even after updating it didn't seem to work